# Combine @WebMcvTest with @PathVariable annotated controllers in Spring Boot 1.41

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

Sample application for this question is here: https://github.com/olemerdy-fa/webmvctest

I am bootstrapping a new project using Spring Boot 1.4.1. I try to leverage the new features from this great framework, especially the ability to (quite-)unit test 'slices' of my application.

I am now struggled with the `@WebMvcTest` feature when used on a `@Controller` declaring a `@PathVariable` annotated method.

Indeed, a `@WebMvcTest` is supposed to bootstrap a single controller and the MockMvc testing facility, without providing anything else. Using `@MockBean`, it's still quite easy to provide mocks as dependencies to inject inside this controller.

But what about a `@PathVariable` annotated parameter whose type is, say, a JPA Entity whose converter is usually registered by Spring Data?

The sample project joined to this question contains a few samples:

- `MyEntity` is a simple JPA entity and `MyEntityRepository` its Spring Data associated repository
- `Webmvctest1Controller` has a `load` method retrieving the id from the path and calls itself the `MyEntityRepository.findOne(id)` method
- `Webmvctest1ControllerUnitTest` tests this controller by mocking `MyEntityRepository` and everything just goes well
- `Webmvctest2Controller` has a `load` method with a `@PathVariable` annotated `MyEntity` which is looked up by Spring Data registered converter

  ```
  @RestController
  public class Webmvctest2Controller {

      @RequestMapping("load2/{id}")
      public MyEntity load2(@PathVariable("id") MyEntity myEntity) {
          return myEntity;
      }

  }
  ```
- `Webmvctest2ControllerUnitTest` is where I'm stuck, as I do not know how to provide a mock entity as the parameter while still using `MockMvc`

  ```
  @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
  @WebMvcTest(Webmvctest2Controller.class)
  public class Webmvctest2ControllerUnitTest {

      @Autowired
      private MockMvc mvc;

      @Test
      public void load2() throws Exception {

          // How do I mock converter to PathVariable here?

          mvc.perform(get("/load2/123").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                  .andExpect(status().isOk())
                  .andExpect(content().json("{id:123,name:'My Entity 123'}"));
      }

  }
  ```

This fails with a `org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException` exception

```
    2016-10-25 14:27:55.699  WARN 20753 --- [           main] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to convert request element: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.stackoverflow.MyEntity]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.stackoverflow.MyEntity]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

    MockHttpServletRequest:
          HTTP Method = GET
          Request URI = /load2/123
           Parameters = {}
              Headers = {Accept=[application/json]}

    Handler:
                 Type = com.stackoverflow.Webmvctest2Controller
               Method = public com.stackoverflow.MyEntity com.stackoverflow.Webmvctest2Controller.load2(com.stackoverflow.MyEntity)

    Async:
        Async started = false
         Async result = null

    Resolved Exception:
                 Type = org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException

    ModelAndView:
            View name = null
                 View = null
                Model = null

    FlashMap:
           Attributes = null

    MockHttpServletResponse:
               Status = 500
        Error message = null
              Headers = {}
         Content type = null
                 Body =
        Forwarded URL = null
       Redirected URL = null
              Cookies = []
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.375 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.stackoverflow.Webmvctest2ControllerUnitTest
    load2(com.stackoverflow.Webmvctest2ControllerUnitTest)  Time elapsed: 0.015 sec  <<< FAILURE!
    java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<500>
            at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
            at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
            at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:664)
            at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
            at com.stackoverflow.Webmvctest2ControllerUnitTest.load2(Webmvctest2ControllerUnitTest.java:28)
```

- `WebmvctestApplicationTests` shows that everything is fine in both cases when the application is fully bootstrapped

Any idea of how I could keep my `@PathVariable` entity parameters while still only testing my web slice with `@WebMvcTest`?
Thanks :)

Comment: _" a @WebMvcTest is supposed to bootstrap a single controller and the MockMvc testing facility, without providing anything else."_ You basically answered your own question, so I'm not sure what answer you expect. You don't need `@WebMvcTest` to use `MockMvc`. More importantly: The request has no body, so why should the method expect an entity as parameter?

Comment: The sample given here is simple to show what is happening. In real world code, the method would not simply forward the entity but could modify it, request subproperty, use multiple convertible methods. Actually, if loading entity in request signature is a concern, the question is still valid with any type whose converter is not natively registered by Spring (say: Joda Money).

Comment: Here, we can test our controller only when loading everything. I am looking for a solution keeping the spirit of slices (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) which only loads the few services of the layer we are testing (here, only the web part, not the data or service layers). What can we do to only load the web controller and mock all its dependencies without modifying the original controller code (I want to keep the @PathVariable rich types and let Spring handle the conversions)?

Comment: As for converters not natively registered by Spring: _"@WebMvcTest will auto-configure the Spring MVC infrastructure and limit scanned beans to ... HandlerMethodArgumentResolver"_. As for _"I am looking for a solution keeping the spirit of slices"_ - Again: You don't need `@WebMvcTest` for that. You can set up `MockMvc` yourself.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the fact that MockMvc can be bootstrapped separately. I wanted to rely to @WebMvcTest to limit the scope of scanned beans. Thanks a lot for pointing Spring scans HandlerMethodArgumentResolver, I will try to add a custom scope registered only for this test and see if it works well for our need here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @zeroflagL hinting about possible contributions to `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, I've come up with a solution that seems to fit my need. Contributing a custom Converter handling the mock entity injection in the controller seems to do the job

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @WebMvcTest(Webmvctest2Controller.class)
    public class Webmvctest2ControllerUnitTest {

        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mvc;

        @Test
        public void load2() throws Exception {
            mvc.perform(get("/load2/123").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().json("{id:123,name:'My Entity'}"));
        }

        @TestConfiguration
        static class InternalConfig {

            @Bean
            WebMvcConfigurer configurer() {
                return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
                        registry.addConverter(String.class, MyEntity.class, id -> {
                            if (id.equals("123")) {
                                MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity(123);
                                myEntity.setName("My Entity");
                                return myEntity;
                            }
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                        });
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

It is not perfect, as the mock Entity cannot be provided by the test method itself but it is still allows the web-unit-test bootstrap and run I wanted to keep.